# Eager Loading Image Transforms In Plugin

Tags: assets, elementcriteriamodel, eager-loading, element

The [craft docs on eager loading](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements) show you how to eager load image transforms in twig.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
   with: [
        ['coolImage', { withTransforms: ['transform'] }]
    ]
}) %}
```

However I can't figure out the syntax for achieving the same functionality within a plugin using the ElementCritereaModel.

I've made various attempts but they've all resulted in HUGE EXPLOSIONS of the php error variety.

```
$criterea->with = [
    "coolImage" => [
        "withTransforms" => ["transform"]
    ],
    "otherAssetField",
    "someCategoryField"
];
```

Of course above wouldn't work because you're switching between field slugs being keys/values in the array.

Using a similar syntax to the docs in twig would be:

```
$criterea->with = [
    "teaserImage",
    ["withTransforms" => ["peopleListing"]],
    "peoplePffice",
    "peopleCategories"
];
```

But that also results in explosions.

Help!!! (thanks)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post while searching for the same answer. Figured it out eventually. For future reference, the correct syntax in a (Craft 2) plugin would be:

```
$criterea->with = [
    ["coolImage", ["withTransforms" => ["transform"]]],
    "otherAssetField",
    "someCategoryField"
];
```